# FrameLayout within a DrawerLayout

Tags: android, xamarin

I would like to wrap into a DrawerLayout a FrameLayout (to replace it on demand with other FrameLayouts at runtime). The Code below is from the GitHub project over [here](https://github.com/PumpingCode/Xamarin-NavigationDrawerDemo).

But If I add a FrameLayout in the LinearLayout below the widget.Toolbar, I receive following exception

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to convert instance of type 'Android.Widget.FrameLayout' to type 'Android.Support.Design.Widget.NavigationView'.
```

Without the FrameLayout it works perfectly. Where should I place the FrameLayout to achieve my goal?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/content_frame"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />    

  </LinearLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:id="@+id/nav_view"
      app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
      app:headerLayout="@menu/header" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The MainAcitivty.cs

```
    drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);

    // Init toolbar
    var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Attach item selected handler to navigation view
    var navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
    navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;

    // Create ActionBarDrawerToggle button and add it to the toolbar
    var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, Resource.String.open_drawer, Resource.String.close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.SyncState();
```

Comment: I think the problem is the actual code you used to get the reference of the view. You can't cast a FrameLayout to a NavigationView. Your XML should not give that error

Comment: I added the code for the corresponding UI. Without the FrameLayout in the axml it works flawlessly.

Comment: I think the FrameLayout should be outside that LinearLayout for the Toolbar, but I don't see anything immediately wrong with this. You should probably be using CoordinatorLayout instead of DrawerLayout anyway

Comment: Your layout is just fine, from a framework standpoint, anyway. I'm not sure if Xamarin injects its own stuff in between, though. It looks like things might've gotten mixed up in the build resources. You might try cleaning and rebuilding your project, however you do that in Xamarin.

Comment: I downloaded the project and inserted `FrameLayout` like your codes. But I didn't have the error. The project runs correctly. Did you modified other parts of the project?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Thanks for the effort. I did the same and couldn't discover the exception again. The error must be somewhere else

Comment: I don't know why it works now, but after cleaning the proj, uninstalling the app from the emu, restarting the PC it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" android:id="@+id/drawer_toolbar"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">
       <!-- app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"-->

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start|right"
            android:divider="#f0f0f0"
            android:dividerHeight="1.5dp"
            android:indicatorEnd="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="visible">
        </ExpandableListView>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```